# Считать строку в Golang, используя буфер

Tags: строки, golang

Есть ли более красивый способ считать строку, обрезая символ переноса строки?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    str, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')
    str = strings.Trim(str, "\n")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться
[`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner):

```golang
var scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", scanner.Text())
}

err = scanner.Err()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: А в чем разница между `NewReader` и `NewScanner`?

Comment: Ну…  Первый создаёт `bufio.Reader`, второй — `bufio.Scanner`.  Это две разных сущности для двух разных целей.

Comment: Вот как раз в различиях этих я бы и хотел разобраться. Когда что применять?

Comment: Ну, опять же.  `bufio.Reader` нужен, когда вам нужна имплементация интерфейса `io.Reader`.  `bufio.Scanner` нужен, когда вам просто надо сканировать текст.